# Draw random number method

Tags: ruby

i'm doing a small lottery ruby program.

i have an issue with how to get an amount of random numbers.

the lottery ticket has a serial number and a lotterynumber.

i use this code to pick 5 numbers.

```
lottery = (1..99999).to_a.sample 5
serial = (1..180).to_a.sample 5
```

the problem is that these take 5 different serial and lottery numbers. i want it to be able to pick the same number as some of the others, it should just not be able to pick both serial and lottery number.

example:

```
Draws:
97449 053
97449 055
33559 053
```

How can i make a method that make sure that it will be able to pick the same serial OR lottery number? but it cant pick the same serial AND lottery number

Comment: You want 5 lottery numbers and one serial number that's different from the lottery numbers, right?

Comment: nope 1 ticket has a lottery number and a serialnumber.
i will draw 5 ticket numbers.
it must not draw identical lottery and the serial number
but it can draw identical lottery number, but then the serial number must be different
it can also draw identical serial number, but then the lottery number must be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this code?

```
tickets = []
while tickets.length < 5
  this_ticket = [rand(99999)+1, rand(180)+1]
  tickets << this_ticket unless tickets.include? this_ticket
end
p tickets

=> [[80947, 67], [61828, 72], [88452, 103], [24607, 84], [18141, 40]]
```

This generates a ticket and only adds it to the list of tickets if it isn't already present.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
(0..18099999).to_a.sample(5).map{|n| [n%100000,n/100000]}
```